# Flyway doesn't create schema version table in provided schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I am working with flyway and spring boot. 2.x.x.  I am able to execute successfully.

But flyway generates new  schema based on my username and write flyway history table into that. As I want to be in my schema. For that I have set  properties

```
    flyway.schemas=xyz
```

But it not creating that table into specified schema xyz.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [FlywayProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayProperties.java) are read from configuration properties with prefix `spring.flyway`

```
spring.flyway.schemas=xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration file name is flyway.properties and it should reside in the same directory as the pom.xml file. Encoding is specified by flyway.encoding (Default is UTF-8).

```
flyway.user=databaseUser
flyway.password=databasePassword
flyway.schemas=schemaName
```

Also, as @Benoit commented, the user should have proper access rights for the specified schema.

Comment: In scope of this question this is not correct. Author is using Flyway plugin for spring-boot which by default reads flyway configurations from properties with prefix `spring.flyway`. See link in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

This behavior does not come from flyway but rather from the underlying database.

Check that this user has the proper rights to:

- Read/Write data in this schema.
- Create a table in this schema.